# Next.js: How to create a dynamic route for all pages present from the API?

Tags: javascript, next.js

Greetings to everyone,

I have just started to learn NodeJS and have been experimenting on API routes in NextJS as its easy to setup and see what's actually going on, So I know how to make a basic get request but I'm interested in something a little complex.

So I'm trying to build an API route that can be filleted by page number, so for example `api/pages/1` would return page 1 and so on.

so this is my file in `/api/game.js`

```
export default async function handler(req,res) {
    const response = await fetch('https://exampleapi.com/pages/?sort=&page=1&per_page=50')
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    res.status(200).json(jsonData);
}
```

Now this works obviously but I want to know how I can make dynamic routes for all the pages. Since I'm using an external API I'm not sure how many pages exist at any moment.

So far I have created another folder and called the file `[gamepage].js`, I'm not sure how I would manipulate the fetch call in the `game.js` file in here.

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
    const { pno } = req.query
    console.log(pro)
    const response = await fetch(`https://exampleapi.com/pages/?sort=&page=${pno}&per_page=50`)
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    res.status(200).json(jsonData);
  }
```

Sorry if the question is too beginner level, I'm just getting started with backend JS.

Comment: IIRC you could get the parameter from `req.params` just like Express?

Comment: So I should set the `req.params` in the first file and then fetch based on that in the dynamic route?

Comment: I think so, if I'm understanding you correctly?

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate the `page=1` in my fetch based on the API route so for example if you go `api/game/3` you get the results of page number 3, Just to be more clear

Comment: The `api` directory is not meant to serve web pages, you use the base dir `pages` directory to serve web pages. If you want to add dynamic params to an api route on the other hand, just create a slug file : `pages/api/[dynamic].js`
So if in page 1 you fetch `/api/1` in `[dynamic].js` you can retrieve the param with `req.query` // 1 . https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/dynamic-api-routes

Comment: Yes, I know I'm not trying to serve web pages of course,  Sorry if got you confused, I'm trying to fetch data for different pages which I can serve to my front end later, I have tried this method and have added my code, It doesn't seem to be changing the pages

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, I was just missing the `gamepage` from `req.query`

```
   const { pno } = req.query.gamepage
```

this did it.